# Change all array values

Tags: php, arrays, string

All values of my arrays in a multidimensional array consists of one variable + string.

How can I change all values from `array[2]` and `array[3]` in my example?
I want to change the variable called `$var` with `$var2` and put another variable called `$between` between `$var2` and the string.

Example

```
$var = "start-";
$array = array
  (
  array("{$var}end1a","{$var}end2a","{$var}end3a"),
  array("{$var}end1b","{$var}end2b","{$var}end3b"),
  array("{$var}end1c","{$var}end2c","{$var}end3c")
  );

    $var2 = "new-start-";
    $between = "between-";
```

result

```
$array[2]=array("{$var2}{$between}end1","{$var2}{$between}end2","{$var2} {$between}end3");
$array[3]=array("{$var2}{$between}end1","{$var2}{$between}end2","{$var2} {$between}end3");
```

UPDATE: First I had only an one-dimensional array and the answer from maxhud was perfect for this case.

Comment: Can you give an example of actual input and actual output?

Comment: invalid psudo code is not a lot of help

Comment: So ultimately you want to transform `start-end1, start-end2` into `new-start-betweenend1, new-start-betweenend2`?

Comment: nah i think he wants `start-end1-betweenend42,ponies`

Comment: new-start-betweenend1,new-start-betweenend2,new-start-betweenend3  is what I want

Comment: And the `"{"`  preceding the first array element - are those present, or pseudocode errors?

Comment: great edited to more invalid psudo code - whats so hard about providing *real* examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$start = "start-";

$array = array(
    array($start."enda1", $start."enda2", $start."enda3"),
    array($start."endb1", $start."endb2", $start."endb3"),
    array($start."endc1", $start."endc2", $start."endc3")
);

$newStart = "new-start-";
$between = "between-";

$keys = array(2, 5);

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    foreach ($array[$key] as $key2 => $value) {
        $array[$key][$key2] = str_replace($start, $newStart.$between, $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works for my case, but I actually want to change some arrays from a multidimensional array. I change my question  ...

Comment: You should ask a new question if you're going to change it significantly.

Comment: @Dagon A poorly asked question doesn't deserve name called. Reign it in.

Comment: Is it significantly, if the array `$array` is a multidimensional array? I want to change some for example only `$array[2]` and `$array[3]` the same way like in your answer.

Comment: Done. I am deeply grateful for your help and patience with me ;-). I think my code isn't invalid now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79472/discussion-between-grischa-and-maxhud).